# PHP Session not recognizing variable when heading to another page

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, get

So I'm making a Login - Successful Login page with PHP, and using MySQL Database. My code successfully checked the Username and Password and only allowed me to head to the next page once they are correct.

However, I cannot print out the Username on Successful Login page. So I'm not sure if my session is running properly or not.

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<!--<form action ="SuccessfulLogin.php" method = "get"> --> // If I put this in my code, the whole program stops checking Username and Password, and just put me to the next page
<?php
//define variables and set to empty values
 $nameErr = $loginErr = "";
 $Username = $website = $Password = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     if (empty($_POST["Username"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
        $Username = test_input($_POST["Username"]);  
      }

      if (empty($_POST["Password"])) {
        $passErr = "Password is required";
      } else {
        $Password = test_input($_POST["Password"]); 
      }
    //continues to target page if all validation is passed
    if ( $unameErr ==""&& $passErr ==""){
        // check if exists in database
        $dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','testuser','password','Project')
        or die("Could not Connect!\n");
        $hashpass=hash('sha256',$Password);
        $sql="SELECT * from Members WHERE Username ='$Username' AND Password='$hashpass';";
        $result =mysqli_Query($dbc,$sql) or die (" Error querying database");
        $a=mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($a===0){
            $loginErr="Invalid username or password";
        }else{ 
            $_SESSION["Username"]=$Username;
            header('Location: /SuccessfulLogin.php');
        }
    }
}

   // clears spaces etc to prep data for testing
function test_input($data){
    $data=trim ($data); // gets rid of extra spaces befor and after
    $data=stripslashes($data); //gets rid of any slashes
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data); //converts any symbols usch as < and > to special characters
    return $data;
}

?>

<h2 style="color:yellow" align="center"> Login </h2>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" align="center" style="color:#40ff00">

 User Name: <input type="text" name="Username" value="<?php echo $Username;?>"/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $unameErr;?></span>
<br/><br/>
Password:
<input type="text" name="Password" value=""/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $passErr;?></span>
<br/><br/>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $loginErr;?></span>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/> 
</form>

<!--</form>--> // closing tag of form action SuccessfulLogin.php
</html>
```

**SuccessfulLogin.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<?php
session_start();
$Username=$_GET['Username'];
$_SESSION['Username']=$Username;
?>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="RegisterLogin.css">
</head>

<body>

<!--<form action ="MemberMenu.php" method = "get">-->

    <h2><?php echo "User $Username LOGGED IN"; ?></h2> // Doesn't print out the $Username

    <p align="center"> <a href="MemberMenu.php"> Click here to be redirected to the menu page </a> </p>


<!--</form>-->
</footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Call `session_start()` before any output for session to not fail.

Comment: What @Mr.Blue is saying is that place `session_start();` before `<!doctype html>` or just remember to place it always first at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check session isset or not.

Change

```
<?php
session_start();
$Username=$_GET['Username'];
$_SESSION['Username']=$Username;
?>
```

With

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
    $Username=$_SESSION['Username'];
    echo $Username;
}
?>
```

Comment: Do I have to put session_start() at login page also?

Answer (score 0):

You're using $_GET["Username"] which will be empty in this example, and then setting $_SESSION["Username"] to the empty variable.

Also this is a very odd way to do user auth.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code

```
<?php
session_start();
$Username=$_SESSION['Username'];
$_SESSION['Username']=$Username;
?>
```

Into:

```
<?php
session_start();
$Username=$_SESSION['Username'];
?>
```

[Read more about PHP session here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: could you explain difference between given answer ans your